# How to make a request to Twitter that authorizes and gets the followers_count

Tags: api, authentication, twitter, request

I've spent the whole day trying to figure out how to actually make a request that's authorized (because twitter wants you to authorize even for data that's public) and gets the followers_count from the user object. The documentation is absolutely terrible. It doesn't tell me how to write the request and where. People are talking about putting headers on servers and all that but I don't understand it

Comment: Post some code you have tried

Comment: Have you tried one of the many language-specific libraries that do the authentication for you? Most APIs require authentication, and Twitter is no different.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I've actually tried, but you need to use php and I don't know how to write my request with the authentication tokens and all that